# Using png files in illustrator for printing invitations

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, png, cmyk

I purchased some pictures to use on party invitations, it said all files are 300 dpi, RGB, transparent background. They are a png file type

I have opened the file in AI and copied the parts I want to my new document which I set up as 300dpi, CMYK. Is there something I need to do to the png before I go to print my file?

I will also be saving as a pdf, I am new to AI, thank you

Comment: How will it be printed?  Digitally on a home inkjet printer, commercial digital printing, or using a print process that requires separations, such as commercial lithographic printing?

Answer (score 0):

First I would put them all in ai file (as you would prepare the invitiation) save as PDF with color profile and send for printing. Just one page with all the pictures.
That would give you information if there is something changing.

I assume what is on those are ornaments with one color. For the sake of quality and safety I would make it only one plate/color. Many printers who are doing invitations have machines set for printing in Gold/Silver/Black/extra instead of CMYK. So it would be easier to have that shape "gold ready".
Second thing is that if it's ornament it could have small intricate lines that, when switched to CMYK, could have those lines not align during printing.

Side note: make sure the PNG don't have any colorprofile embbeded. I hade some PDF's in CMYK that had transparent files with RGB profiles in it and it made RIP goes crazy.

Comment: Hi, the png’s are watercolour floral pictures.

Comment: @0202 Then I would definitelly print them first solo. RGB watercolours can look pretty good on the screen but in print a slight change in one color can put your color off. Especially if the picture is light green or blue.

Comment: Hi, I opened the png on my laptop and printed to both my home printers without going through AI and the colours are not great on my new printer. I’m wondering if the issue is the new printer? Pinks look orangey / red tint to them. Canon 3600 colours are great, canon iP8750 pinks are not great.